# split planned hours between resources using excel formula or excel vba

Tags: vba, excel

I required output like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mnm2G.jpg). I have planned hours for each month and want to split planned hours between two resources from their start date and end date. Example: For manager role planned hours for june month are 80. Resource 1 is working from 1-Apr to 15-Jun and resource 2 is working from 16-Jun to 30-Sept then formula or code should split june hours between this two resources. Like I shown below

[image]

Any thoughts? I don't mind if it's an Excel formula or a vba code

using below formula I am getting output for engineer role but not for manager role.

```
=IF(AND($D4<=F$3,$E4>=EOMONTH(F$3,0)),80,0)
```

[image: output]

Comment: I would recommend using formulae, or even just hard code the values.

Comment: will your split always be 1/2 the month?  or will you have splits where people can start on any date?  Ie one start on april 1st and the other start on april 2nd?

Comment: I want to split hours by start and end date. If resource 1 is working for 7 days then hours should be 20.

Comment: what if they are working for 3 days? or will it always be full weeks? what about weeks that start in one month and finish in another, how would they get split if you a breaking things up by weeks (ie 7 days)?

Comment: basically hours are divided in 4 weeks, if resource 1 is working for 3 days then split should be 20-60

Comment: 7 days to a week, 4 weeks to a month.  That is 28 day...what happens in every month except February that has more than 28 days?  Right now the problem the way I see it is how you are defining your 7 seven days.  if you go straight 7 days, you can see it does not fit into every month.  if you go by weeks, you have not stated how you are treating weeks that start in one month and finish in the next.  Ie if monday is the last day of the month, is that week in the current month or the next month?  same as if thursday were the last day of the month, is the week current month or next month?

Comment: assuming 4 week in a month which are divided like this, day 1-7,8-15,16-23,24-31.

Comment: just clarifying, so if someone started on the 7th and finished on the 8th of the same month, they would have their hours split over 2 weeks since their start and end date were in week 1 and week 2?

Comment: in this case he has worked for 2 days that means he falls in first category ie day 1-7, so split should be 20

Comment: You could use this function to get the days of the month you are looking for `intDaysInMonth = day(DateSerial(Year(monthYear), Month(monthYear) + 1, 0))` And then try to input some `If Statements` And this gets you the monthYear `monthYear = (Right(ThisWorkbook.ActiveSheet.Range("C10"), 7))` Or you could just subtract dates.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I wonder if this formula will work for you.

`=ROUND((MAX(F$12-MAX($C13,E$12),0)-MAX(F$12-MAX($D13,E$12),0))*E$11/30,-1)`

In this example, columns C and D hold the resources' start and end dates.
E12 holds the date of Apr 1, 2017, F12 the formula `=EDATE(E12,1)` copied to the right as far as required. You can format these dates to show just month and year as per your form but the formula expects them to be the first day of each month.

E$11 holds the value of 80 (hours) in your example.

Comment: If I enter 85 hours in this formula then its giving wrong values. Planned hours are not fixed they may varies.

Comment: The formula correctly calculates the days. It then converts the days into a portion of 80 (I will change this to refer to the value in what is row 11 in my example) in a very roughshod manner. The thing to do is to specify the conversion formula. You have been very vague on this.

Comment: I wonder if a divisor of 28 instead of 30 might enable a better estimate. I haven't thought this through hoping you will :-). The other thing is that my formula rounds to the nearest 10 hours. Perhaps the nearest 5 would be a better match. Replace the `-1` in the formula with `0` to test the formula with full hours.

Comment: I did some changes in this, its working with below formula =IF(AND($C13<=E$12,$D13>=EOMONTH(E$12,0)),E$11,ROUND((MAX(F$12-MAX($C13,E$12),0)-MAX(F$12-MAX($D13,E$12),0))*E$11/DAY(EOMONTH(E$12,0)),0))

Answer (score 0):

Its a little convoluted and formula maintenance will be a pain in the arse, but the formula below pasted into F2 and copied down and right seems to work:

```
=IF(OR(EOMONTH(F$3,0)<EOMONTH($D4,0),EOMONTH(F$3,0)>EOMONTH($E4,0)),0,
IF(IF(EOMONTH($D4,0)=EOMONTH($E4,0),$E4-$D4,IF(EOMONTH($D4,0)=EOMONTH(F$3,0),EOMONTH(F$3,0)-$D4+1,IF(EOMONTH($E4,0)=EOMONTH(F$3,0),$E4-F$3+1,DAY(EOMONTH(F$3,0)))))<=7,1,
IF(IF(EOMONTH($D4,0)=EOMONTH($E4,0),$E4-$D4,IF(EOMONTH($D4,0)=EOMONTH(F$3,0),EOMONTH(F$3,0)-$D4+1,IF(EOMONTH($E4,0)=EOMONTH(F$3,0),$E4-F$3+1,DAY(EOMONTH(F$3,0)))))<=15,2,
IF(IF(EOMONTH($D4,0)=EOMONTH($E4,0),$E4-$D4,IF(EOMONTH($D4,0)=EOMONTH(F$3,0),EOMONTH(F$3,0)-$D4+1,IF(EOMONTH($E4,0)=EOMONTH(F$3,0),$E4-F$3+1,DAY(EOMONTH(F$3,0)))))<=23,3,4))))/4*F$2
```

I would work nicer with some intermediate cell calculations in order to avoid the repeated nested if statements.  I am sure it can be simplified.

[image: POC]